# Swift || do we possible to detect how many spaces of empty string have?

Tags: swift

lets say we have an extension of String:

```swift
extension String {
  var textBeCleared: Bool {
   // how we write here
  }
}
```

then:

```swift
var demo1 = ""  // no space over here
demo.textBeCleared // true
var demo2 = " " // type one space over here
demo.textBeCleared // false
```

because I got a sticky issue is: I have a save button at bottom of a text field, save button only displays when removing all text contents in the text field, like demo1. but if type more space over here, like demo2, save button will be hidden.

Comment: Depending on your uses, you could also trim (with `.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)`) to remove white space at start & end of the string, and use that trimmed string to check also if it's empty.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you could try this:

```
extension String {
  var textBeCleared: Bool {
      self.isEmpty
  }
}

var demo1 = ""  // no space over here
var demo2 = " " // type one space over here
print(" demo1.textBeCleared: \(demo1.textBeCleared) ") // true
print(" demo2.textBeCleared: \(demo2.textBeCleared) ") // false
```

Comment: Creating another property with the exact behavior of isEmpty collection property is pointless

Answer (score 0):

User **filter** for this purpose. It will filter each char in the string and you will get your expected result.

```
let inputString1 = "   "
let inputString2 = ""
let inputString3 = "a"
let spacesCount1 = inputString1.filter { $0 == " " }
print(spacesCount1.count)
let spacesCount2 = inputString2.filter { $0 == " " }
print(spacesCount2.count)
let spacesCount3 = inputString3.filter { $0 == " " }
print(spacesCount3.count)
```

Output

```
3
0
0
```

Comment: hi I tried write an extension like below:
extension String {
    var textBeCleared: Bool {
        return self.filter { $0 == " "}
    }
}
but i got an error: No 'filter' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'Bool'

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys, I managed solved this by following code

```swift
let inputString1 = "   "
let inputString2 = ""
let inputString3 = "a"


extension String {
    var textBeCleared: Bool {
        !self.contains(" ") && allSatisfy { $0.isWhitespace }
    }
}
inputString1.textBeCleared // false
inputString2.textBeCleared // true
inputString3.textBeCleared // false
```

Comment: Note, you can achieve the same results with just `self.isEmpty` as in my answer.